# Is there any way I can freeze first column(always display) while horizontal scrolling?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

Is there any way I can freeze first column(always display) while horizontal scrolling? As displayed in the below picture, I want to show Title column always while scrolling horizontally

Comment: it might help to share the html that you use to generate the table

Answer (score 6):

Check out the documentation on Pinning: 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/203_pinning

You basically add pinning to the module:

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pinning']);`

... and add the pinning directive to your grid element:

`<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-pinning></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Click[here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/203_pinning) Click on the link,the link solved my issue. This is what exactly I was looking for.